# How to find out the shell script file of a custom Command in Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

Is there a way to find the .sh file located in the system for a custom command

Comment: can you give an example for what "custom command" you want to find a "sh" file?

Comment: @StefanHegny long back I had created a script file which takes backup of my DB and sends it to other server , I called it 'my_script' and added it to cron , Now I have forgotten where exactly the script file located

Comment: Look in your crontab.

Comment: @MarkSetchell in my crontab it just says the command with the time it has to execute

Comment: So, if the command is `fred.sh`, try running `type fred.sh` in your Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these options - first ones are fastest:

- `type my_script`
- `locate my_script`
- `find / -type f -name my_script`